# Reorder dom not binding to vue array instance?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Now I am developing a Framework7 app with vue 2.x. In my app, there is a list which is sortable throught drag and drop. I can use the sortable list in Framework7 directly; However, after sorting throught drag and drop, the corresponding list data in vue instance doesn't change. I am not sure if it is Framework7 issue and belive that it is the vue hack, so following simplist code can show my problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sorting List</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <ul>
        <li v-for="item in list">{{ item }}</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Now items are: {{ list }}</p>
    <p><button @click="operate">Click me to move the 2nd item before 1st one.</button></p>
</div>

<script src="lib/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="lib/vue@2.3.2.js"></script>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            list: ['one', 'two', 'three']
        },
        methods: {
            operate: function () {
                // the following code simulate the Framework7 drag and drop effect
                var li = $('ul li:eq(1)');
                li.remove();
                $('ul li:eq(0)').before(li);

                // I want to search a method to update the list order, however, the following code cannot show my desired effect
//                this.list = ['two', 'one', 'three']; // Not function
            }
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want after clicking the button the list items become `["two", "one", "three"]`

Comment: I think the core of your problem is that you are modifying the DOM itself. You should use your business logic to modify the data and the framework (Vue) will change the DOM to reflect the changes in your data. Making changes to the DOM will not cause changes to your data.

Comment: @wing if the problem is about rearranging a list with drag and drop, in that case, dom will update the data. Just like we create dynamic menus in any app.

Comment: @Deepak: ahh, I missed the mentions of drag and drop and focused on the requirement of sorting and the code that did a lot of DOM modifications. But, yes, you are right – dragging and dropping elements (modifying the DOM) should update the ViewModel in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Vue will handle the DOM updates automatically, so you simply need to change the order of the elements in the array in your `operate` method and the DOM will update:

```
operate: function () {
  this.list = ['two', 'one', 'three']; 
}
```

---

If you actually want to rearrange the list instead of completely redefining it, you'll need to call `$set()` or `splice()` on the array (see the [common beginner gotchas](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/)):

```
operate: function() {
  var temp = this.list[0];
  this.list.$set(0, this.list[1]);
  this.list.$set(1, temp);
}
```

Comment: No, no, no, maybe I haven't expressed clearly my problem. I am using the Framework7 for my little app, and the drag and drop logic is handled by Framework7 automaticly. So the dom operating code just simulates the effect, it cannot be removed.

Comment: @Run in that case, there's a vue plugin for Framework7 that you should use: https://framework7.io/vue/